# Ingress routing not working for services deployed with helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I deployed a helm chart (`helm install --name=my-release stable/kube-ops-view`) which created a svc with clusterIP, I tried to create a route to it via traefik ingress, but its not working

I have been able to route other applications (nginx) using similar ingress configurations

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  namespace: kube-ops-view #svc is created in this namespace
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /kube
        backend:
          serviceName: kube-ops-view
          servicePort: 80
```

Ingress should have worked

Comment: response recieved :
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>

Comment: If you change this ingress path value listed here https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/kube-ops-view/values.yaml#L24 to `/kube` I don;t think it would work unless kube-ops-view have some way to override its base-path.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work on GKE cluster.
After cluster creation :

1) Installed Helm

2) Installed NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)

Next..
You should use [Rewrite target](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target) with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` [annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/).

> Starting in Version 0.22.0, ingress definitions using the annotation
>   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target are not backwards
>   compatible with previous versions. In Version 0.22.0 and beyond, any
>   substrings within the request URI that need to be passed to the
>   rewritten path must explicitly be defined in a capture group.

you ingress should look like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: kubeops-kube-ops-view
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kubeops-kube-ops-view
          servicePort: 80
        path: /kube(/?|$)(.*)
```

And another option: you can enable ingress in helm chart without writing ingress yaml.

My way:

```
helm fetch stable/kube-ops-view --untar
```

edit values.yaml

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  path: /kube(/|$)(.*)
# hostname: kube-ops-view.local
  annotations: {
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx,
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  }
  tls: []
  ## Secrets must be manually created in the namespace
  #   - secretName: kube-ops-view.local-tls
  #     hosts:
  #       - kube-ops-view.local
```

edit templates/ingress.yaml

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "kube-ops-view.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "kube-ops-view.fullname" . }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
{{- if .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.ingress.annotations | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  rules:
    - host:
      http:
        paths:
          - path: {{ .Values.ingress.path }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ template "kube-ops-view.fullname" . }}
              servicePort: {{ .Values.service.externalPort }}
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
{{ toYaml .Values.ingress.tls | indent 4 }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Verify and install:
helm install --server-dry-run --debug  kube-ops-view
helm install kube-ops-view --name kubeops

Check Result:

```
curl -iLk http://Ingress-external-ip/kube/
HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
Server: openresty/1.15.8.1
Date: Thu, 22 Aug 2019 09:21:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 177
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://Ingress-external-ip/kube/

HTTP/2 200 
server: openresty/1.15.8.1
date: Thu, 22 Aug 2019 09:21:21 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 1276
vary: Accept-Encoding
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Kubernetes Operational View 0.11</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/favicon.ico">
<style>* {padding: 0; margin: 0} body { color: #aaaaff; background: #000; }</style>
<style>
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ShareTechMono';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  /* ShareTechMono-Regular.ttf: Copyright (c) 2012, Carrois Type Design, Ralph du Carrois (www.carrois.com post@carrois.com), with Reserved Font Name 'Share'
     License: SIL Open Font License, 1.1 */
  src: local('Share Tech Mono'), local('ShareTechMono-Regular'), url(static/sharetechmono.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- make sure the font is loaded -->
        <div id="loading" style="font-family: ShareTechMono">Loading..</div>
        <script src="static/build/app-ee71ac795470b05e7f76.js"></script>
        <script>document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none'; const app = new App(); app.run()</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]